# C++ MFC, Get GUI Control using a ID variable

Tags: c++, mfc

I was wondering if it is possible to get a MFC GUI Control with a variable acting as its ID. I have several controls I would like to change at once i.e. IDC_btn30, IDC_btn29 etc so this would be far more code efficient if possible.

```
 int days = 31;
 std::string id = "IDC_btn" + days;
 GetDlgItem(id)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

Comment: The `GetDlgItem()` function takes an integer ID as a parameter. And a control's ID doesn't change during its lifetime. So how this could not be possible? It's exactly the same as calling `GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)`. I do not understand the question, I'm afraid.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I meant would it be possible to make the program think that GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1) was the same as GetDlgItem(id) that way I could change the number at the end of the ID. Is that more clear?

Comment: The IDs are integers though, Well, some programmers would be tempted to use some... ID logic, like consecutive IDs (eg `baseID + n`), but this is generally not recommended, as a resource editor or manager could re-arrange the IDs. But it is possible, if you create the controls programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I've done this is by creating a header file that gives a fixed mapping of a range of control IDs to an increasing sequence of integers:

```
#define IDC_BUTTON1  2001
#define IDC_BUTTON2  2002
#define IDC_BUTTON3  2003
#define IDC_BUTTON4  2004
```

etc.

The .rc file then needs to be set to include that header. In Visual Studio, this is done by adding it to the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource. In a file generated by AppWizard, this reads:

```
2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
EN
```

Add your header so that it reads:

```
2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "#include ""myres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
EN
```

This entry can also be added through the Visual Studio IDE by switching to the resource view in the project window, right-clicking on the appropriate .rc file and selecting "Resource includes...". Then `#include "myres.h"` should be added to the "Read-only symbol directives" section. Other resource editors may have their own techniques to do this.

Also `#include` the header file in the implementation file for your window class.

You will then be able to calculate control IDs within that range, for example in loops like:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
{
    GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1 + n)->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

---

Another technique, less elegant but more self-contained, is to create an array of control IDs in your implementation file and loop over that:

```
static const int Controls[] = 
{ 
    IDC_FRAME1, IDC_RADIO1, IDC_RADIO2, IDC_BUTTON1, IDC_BUTTON2 
};
```

...

```
for (int n = 0; n < _countof(Controls); n++)
{
    GetDlgItem(Controls[n])->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

Comment: I've done the latter - seems less of a hack than dealing with VS Resource Editor behavior.